# SharePoint 2010 keywordQuery

Tags: 2010, search, sandbox-solution, splistitem, attachments

I am using the **keyworkQuery** class to fetch some items from a Sharepoint 2010 list.
I need to fetch also the **Attachments** for each item how can I do?.

I tried:

```
KeywordQuery kw = new KeywordQuery(proxy);
kw.SelectProperties.Add("Attachments");
```

But I get this error:

> Property doesnt exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such managed property for the attachments in SharePoint 2010, so the error occurred.

If you search for the attachment, the list item returns, so the attachment itself cannot be returned by the search.

Check those:
http://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/are-list-attachments-indexed-in-sharepoint-search/

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=83